# how to get element from XML using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I have to change my project form XML to JavaScript (at least some parts of it).
So I had construction like this :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://...);
$profile = $xml->profile;   
$user_id = $profile->user_id;
```

Now I wanted to translate this into JavaScript so I used :

```
var xmlHttp_subscribe = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp_subscribe.onreadystatechange=postCall;
xmlHttp_subscribe.open("GET","http://...",true);
xmlHttp_subscribe.send();
```

and now function postCall()

```
function postCall(){
  var t = document.getElementsByName("MY_API").value;
  alert('t'+t);
  var p = document.getElementsByName("profile").value;
  alert('p'+p);
  var h = document.getElementsByName("user_id").value;
//...//
 }
```

The XML is under my http:// is like that :

```
<MY_API>
  <profile>
    <user_id>the_user_id</user_id>
  </profile>
</MY_API>
```

What I would like to do is to get this 'the_user_id' part as string in plain text.
Does any one have any idea how to do this?
Am I looking in the good direction?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function "getElementsByName".  What you need is getElementsByTagName.

[Check this link out, it should be what you're looking for](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)

Comment: Your answer is confusing because there is no function "getElementsByName", but only "getElementsByTagName".

Comment: Thanks gwag.  Edited answer appropriately.

Comment: The mechanize works, but the API that I use to obtain the XML file is misbehaving. So this is my problem. Many Thanks for ur answer.

Comment: No worries. Also be aware that any white space between nodes can affect your results.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Pineda, the right function name is `getElementsByTagName`, and in addition the right property name is not "value" but `nodeValue`, so you should use

```
function postCall(){
  var h = document.getElementsByTagName("user_id").nodeValue;
}
```